# rails 5 HABTM associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

How can I get all Skills that does not already exist in the UserSkill table for current_user?

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :user_skills
    has_many :skills, through: :user_skills
end

class Skill < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :user_skills
    has_many :users, through: :user_skills
   end

class UserSkill < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :skill
end
```

I have tried this:

```
@available_user_skills = Skill.includes(:user_skills).where.not( :user_skills => { :user_id => current_user } )
```

Which just loads all Skills that exist in the Skills table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

```
user_skill_ids = UserSkill.where(user_id: current_user.id).pluck(:skill_id)
not_user_skills = Skill.where.not(id: user_skill_ids)
```

or in one line

```
not_user_skills = Skill.where.not(id: current_user.skills.pluck(:id))
```

Here not_user_skills are the skills that don't belong to the current_user

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi RSB – same result all skills are loaded.

Comment: Try the second approach I just added.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
Skill.includes(:user_skills).where.not(user_skills: {users: {id: current_user.id}})
```

Comment: Get this error `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.id: SELECT "skills"."id" AS t0_r0, "skills"."name" AS t0_r1, "skills"."created_at" AS t0_r2, "skills"."updated_at" AS t0_r3, "user_skills"."id" AS t1_r0, "user_skills"."user_id" AS t1_r1, "user_skills"."skill_id" AS t1_r2 FROM "skills" LEFT OUTER JOIN "user_skills" ON "user_skills"."skill_id" = "skills"."id" WHERE ("users"."id" != ?)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Skill.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN user_skills ON skills.id = user_skills.skill_id").where("user_skills.user_id != #{current_user.id}")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: LEFT JOIN will return all the skills

Comment: Where clause will filter out skills. Tried to do this in a single query.